# Jar files grayed out in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

[image]

I have a java application in eclipse and the thing is that some of the jar files within the project are grayed out.

What does this mean?

The project runs as expected and they are set correctly within the build path.

Comment: Not sure about eclipse but within Intelli J greyed out jar files means they have not been referenced yet within the application

Comment: Could you provide screenshot of the jars?

Comment: Eclipse states the the file are referenced by the project if I try to delete them

Comment: Jar screen added.

Answer (score 0):

These (JAR) files are not under version control (if using Git, these files has been added to `.gitignore`, e. g. via right-click *Team > Ignore*).